# SwiftUI binding / subscription working from UIKit to SwitUI but changes not observer within SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I've got a View in SwiftUI that I've embedded into a UITableViewCell (in UIKit land). The subscription / binding etc works (as I can see print statements in my table cell against the subscription), but within my SwiftUI view, the image does not flip when the flag is toggled. Any idea why?

```
public class CollapsableSectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isExpanded = true

  public init(isExpanded: Bool = true) {
    self.isExpanded = isExpanded
  }
}

public struct CollapsableTableSectionContentView: View {
  @Binding var sectionModel: CollapsableSectionViewModel

  public init(sectionModel: Binding<CollapsableSectionViewModel>) {
    self._sectionModel = sectionModel
  }

  public var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      withAnimation {
        self.sectionModel.isExpanded.toggle()
      }
    }) {
      Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
        .frame(minWidth: 16, minHeight: 16)
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: self.sectionModel.isExpanded ? 90 : 180))
        .padding(.trailing, 16)
    }
    .frame(minHeight: 44)
  }
}
```

And in UIKit:

```
...
let model = CollapsableSectionViewModel(isExpanded: true)

    innerHostedView = UIHostingController(rootView: CollapsableTableSectionContentView(sectionModel: .constant(model)))
    innerHostedView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(innerHostedView.view)
    innerHostedView.view.backgroundColor = .clear

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      innerHostedView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
      innerHostedView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
      innerHostedView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
      innerHostedView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    ])

    expansionSubscription = innerHostedView.rootView.sectionModel.$isExpanded.sink { (expanded) in

      print("Expanded: \(expanded)")
    }
...
```

`Expanded: true` and `Expanded: false` get printed on the console as I tap on the button, but the Chevron image does not alter. It is as though the binding isn't working deeper within the SwiftUI View hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Doh. I was accidentally using `@Binding` when I should have been using `@ObservedObject`. This will need some getting used to. The following changes fixed the binding.

```
  @ObservedObject var sectionModel: CollapsableSectionViewModel
  @Environment(\.locale) var locale

  public init(sectionModel: CollapsableSectionViewModel) {
    self.sectionModel = sectionModel
  }
```